# Basement duct installation with fire sprinkler pipe

Tags: basement, ducts, fire-sprinkler

Can I install a metal HVAC duct with register into the same ceiling joist bay as an orange fire sprinkler pipe, parallel to it? The sprinkler pipe has 2 heads on it.

Comment: Are there heads off this line?  That's the key question here...

Comment: Yes, it has 2 head on the line.

Comment: Then the question becomes "where is this duct going with regards to the throw pattern of the heads?" Also, is this a single-family home, a duplex, a low-rise residential structure (i.e. 4 stories or less), or something bigger?

Comment: Single family home, 2 story home with basement.  2 rooms were unfinished, this is the movie room, but the register wasn't in the main room, so the plan is to reroute it.  A channel is directly in line, but the joist has the sprinkler line.  The duct would be above and on the opposite site of the sprinkler line. Maybe I need to turn the duct into another joist channel.

Comment: The heads are mounted pointing downward correct?

Comment: yes, downward and in code.  90% of the basement was finished...all bot 400 sqft.